# Is there any way to bypass the credential prompt when using CredSSP authentication to be able to run unattended commands?

Tags: windows, powershell, authentication, biztalk

I fell into a double-hop issue while trying to deploy BizTalk apps(msi) to remote machines via powershell. The only way out of this(double-hop) is to use CredSSP authentication for remote session. The deployment needs to be unattended, but if I try to use CredSSP authentication it asks for credentials in a prompt. Is there any way to bypass this manual input of credentials when using CredSSP? If not, is there any other way delegation of credentials can be done without keeping the credentials in the script file?

Comment: CredSSP is not the only way around the double-hop issue.  Delegated constrained sessions will allow you to have one more hop from the remote machine, and don't expose your credentials.

Comment: @mjolinor Thanks. can you please link me to any page that gives an idea about that sort of delegation? I found [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dbb9141d-ce8d-48be-9ed1-9142beb51652) and this does not give a clear idea of which machines/hops needs the delegation enabled, and which services I should delegate. But that's a good starting point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get around the second-hop issue by using remote delegated sessions.
[here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/taylorb/archive/2012/03/26/remote-administration-with-powershell-3-0-sessions-part-1.aspx) is a link to an MSDN article describing how to create these.

Basically, it is the same mechanism that Exchange uses for their remote management sessions.  A remote session configuration is created on the target machine, and whatever runs in that session executes under a set of credentials specified in the `RunAs` parameter of the configuration. When you run something in one of those sessions, you can make one more hop from that machine to another machine without CredSSP because the credential that's actually executing the commands hasn't made a hop yet.

You can get very granular about what scripts, functions, and cmdlets can be run in that session so you can limit it to only being used for a specific purpose.  Once you have it set up, you then limit who has permission to use the session by granting the Execute permission for the session to specific groups or users.

Comment: Thank you! This is the perfect solution. best part is the granular control of permissions :)